# how do I control where gradle/gradlew files and folders are located

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

In a new project - in which I am using gradle/gradlew - I want to set the location of various gradle/gradlew files and folders to something different than the default behaviour.

I am talking about:

- folder gradle, with sub folder wrapper (holding gradle-wrapper.jar and gradle-wrapper.properties
- folder build, with sub folders 'classes', 'dependency-cache', 'libs', 'resources' having all kinds of xml files from individual components, and 'tmp' having sub folders 'compileJava' and 'jar'.

But how and where do I configure this?

Comment: Why would you want to change? Remember, its convention over configuration. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are correct: it is convention over configuration. But the convention (call it the company policy drives the convention in this scenario). Thus the default provided can't be applied.

Comment: I am wondering how there can be an established convention for a Wrapper yet. Most other build tools do not support a Wrapper. Maven only just recently added one. It will make it much harder to understand a build for anyone new to the project if default conventions are changed.

Comment: The convention is really annoying when combined with shell auto-complete. Without the wrapper I can type `grad[tab]` and it auto-completes to `gradle ` (including the trailing space) and I type the rest of my command. With the wrapper, I type `./gra[tab]` and it autocompletes to `./gradle` which isn't the wrapper, it's the folder the wrapper is in, so I have to press `w ` after the tab before I enter any options. Being able to rename the `gradle` folder would be really handy.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the location of the Wrapper and properties file by setting up a task of type [Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/wrapper/Wrapper.html#setJarFile(java.lang.Object)). For example:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    jarFile = file('mywrapper/wrapper.jar')
}
```

Running `gradle wrapper` will generate the following files:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── mywrapper
    ├── wrapper.jar
    └── wrapper.properties
```

The default build output directory can be changed via the method [Project.setBuildDir(Object)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#setBuildDir(java.lang.Object)). For example:

```
buildDir = file('target')
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin.

Thanks for the time to answer the question:

I have a little follow up question: how do I ensure that the downloaded external libraries get download to a folder inside my project, and not in a hidden directory in the directory of the user?

Comment: Gradle downloads dependencies into local its cache in Gradle user home (by default `~/.gradle`). The cache is shared among projects. If you'd change Gradle user home to a project directory then you'd have to change it for every project. This will have a negative impact on your build performance as downloaded dependencies and wrappers cannot be shared anymore.

Comment: I understand that this creates a unique set per project, but this is required in the deployment process towards UAT and PROD servers that are geared towards maximum uptime and performance.

Comment: I don't understand the argument and its relevance for Gradle user home. Can you clarify?